# UITableView Using Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, customization

My **TapCell1.swift**

This is Custom `UITableViewCell View`

```
import UIKit

class TapCell1: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet var labelText : UILabel

    init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!)
    {
        println("Ente")
        super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {

        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

My **ViewController.swift**

Its All DataSource and Delegates are set correctly.But My custom Cell is not displaying.

```
import UIKit

class NextViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
    {
        @IBOutlet var label: UILabel

        @IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView

        var getvalue = NSString()

        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            label.text="HELLO GOLD"

            println("hello : \(getvalue)")
            self.tableView.registerClass(TapCell1.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }

        func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int)->Int
        {
            return 5
        }

        func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView:UITableView!)->Int
        {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
        {
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TapCell1
            cell.labelText.text="Cell Text"
            return cell
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
}
```

The Problem is My custom cell is Not displayed. Please suggest anything i did wrong.

**Note: here is My code [My File Download Link](https://www.mediafire.com/?qay0qcv294heeu2)**

Comment: Are you sure that this line is correct? 
`self.tableView.registerClass(TapCell1.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")`
try to remove .self

Comment: `TapCell1.self` is equivalent to `TapCell1.class` in Objective-C.

Comment: Okay I will check @eXhausted

Comment: Are you using a atoryboard or a nib?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I finally did it.

**For TapCell1.swift**

```
import UIKit

class TapCell1: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var labelTitle: UILabel

    init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
}
```

**For NextViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class NextViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView

    var ListArray=NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nibName = UINib(nibName: "TapCell1", bundle:nil)
        self.tableView.registerNib(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        for i in 0...70 {
            ListArray .addObject("Content: \(i)")
        }
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)->Int {
       return ListArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 51
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TapCell1

        //cell.titleLabel.text = "\(ListArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.item))"

        cell.labelTitle.text = "\(ListArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))"

        return cell
    }
}
```

My working code link: [CUSTOMISED TABLE](http://www.mediafire.com/download/z1v821ib7j8flo8/MAINTABLECUSTOMIZATION%282%29.zip)

Comment: @MoorthyTheBoss: it's*

Comment: The correct answer comes from @Micah: you must add `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in your code, it's an Xcode 6 (as of yet, beta6) bug. Nothing else is relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: should it be `0...70` (three dots not two)?

Comment: Swift 1.2 in Xcode 6.3 suggests that the as needs to be as!

Answer (score 9):

You should register the `class` for the cell. For that do
change this line of code to

```
self.tableView.registerClass(TapCell1.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Edit

You code is looks fine i checked it

```
//cell.labelText.text="Cell Text"

cell.textLabel.text="Cell Text"   // use like this
```

Comment: Yes I know. Its already worked for me.But I need to display TapCell1

Comment: Now its displaying TapCell1 only. what else you want

Comment: TapCell1 colour is green. Finally i did. Thanks for your Valuable time.

Comment: This fixed my problem - but I'm confused, I set this up in Storyboard correctly, so why do i need to manually register in code also? This is different than objc. Any ideas?

Comment: @g_pass if you are using prototype cell in the storyboard no need to register it again by code. if you are using a custom cell only you could register it either by `registerCell` or `registerNib`

Comment: @anil thanks! I was going crazy here, and it was because I had an extra storyboard with the same named prototype cells, cleaned that up and everything is great - pure storyboard now.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is most likely pinpointed to setting the cell height manually as such:

```
override func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->CGFloat
{
    return 44
}
```

I believe it's an Xcode beta 6 bug.

Answer (score 1):

I have now been able to get Custom UITableViewCell to work.

## Works on

- Runs on Xcode 6 beta 6
- Runs on Xcode 6 beta 5
- iOS is 7.1

## How

- I have created a ".xib" file for the cell.
- I copy it into the storyboard.
- Via the storyboard I give it a Identifier.
- I make sure it is a sub child of a tableview

Doing it this way, you do not need to register a class / nib etc.

This is my custom cell.

```
import UIKit

class TestCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var titleImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

In your view, or where ever you extend "UITableViewDataSource".
Make sure "cell2" is the same as the "Identifier" that you gave it via the storyboard.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var cell:TestCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TestCell

    // Example of using the custom elements.
    cell.titleLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    var topImage = UIImage(named: "fv.png")
    cell.titleImageView.image = topImage

    return cell
}
```

[uitableviewcell](/questions/tagged/uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Story board select the cell and look at the "identity inspector in that select CLASS type your CustomClass and MODULE type your project name

I have done this It works perfectly try this tip to avoid error to see below image and code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {

 // let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

  //  cell.textLabel.text = array[indexPath!.row] as String

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell

    cell.nameLabel.text = array[indexPath!.row] as String
    cell.RestaurentView.image = UIImage(named:images[indexPath!.row])

    return cell
}
```

Comment: This helped me after 1 hour of pain. I thought the problem was swift related because I am just starting out in swift. But this shows I should have been thinking out of the box and done some basic checks first.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code

`var cell:CustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomTableViewCell") as CustomTableViewCell`

https://github.com/iappvk/TableView-Swift

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Storyboard then create a new file  as subclass of UITableViewCell check the checkbox "also create xib files" after that set your custom cell .and  here is the code for tableview

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
   {

    var customcell:CustomTableViewCellClass? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? CustomTableViewCellClass
    if  (customcell==nil)
    {
        var nib:NSArray=NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomTableViewCellClass", owner: self, options: nil)

        customcell = nib.objectAtIndex(0) as? CustomTableViewCell
    }

    return customcell!


}
```

Comment: -1, its old method, you should use tableView.registerNib(,forCellReuseIdentifier:) in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCellTableView") as? CustomCellTableView
```

Answer (score 0):

**Extention of NSOject**

```
extension NSObject {    
    var name: String {
        return String(describing: type(of: self))
    } 
    class var name: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}
```

**Properties on Custom TableViewCell**

```
class var nib: UINib {
    return UINib(nibName:YourTableViewCell.name, bundle: nil)
}
class var idetifier: String {
    return YourTableViewCell.name
}
```

**Add in UIViewController**

```
self.tableView.registerNib(YourTableViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: YourTableViewCell.idetifier)

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(YourTableViewCell.idetifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell
```

Answer (score -2):

It is Purely swift notation an working for me

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{ 
var cellIdentifier:String = "CustomFields" 
var cell:CustomCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? CustomCell
 if (cell == nil) 
{ 
var nib:Array = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomCell", owner: self, options: nil) cell = nib[0] as? CustomCell
 } 
return cell! 
}
```