# How to Set UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle and dequeueReusableCell in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'd like a `UITableView` with `subtitle`-style cells that use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

My original Objective-C code was:

```
static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
}
```

After searching the few `UITableView` questions here already on SO, I thought to write it in Swift like so:

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

But that doesn't let me say I want a `subtitle` style.  So I tried this:

```
var cell :UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Which gives me a `subtitle` cell, but it doesn't let me `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

I've researched some more and looked at [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tq0nkr9nhyk), but he creates a separate `subclass` of `UITableViewCell` which I assume is unnecessary as I accomplished this same effect previously in Obj-C.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "it doesn't let me `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`"? It is unclear to me.

Comment: @68cherries Sorry I didn't mean 'feature', didn't know what to call it.  Method?  Basically, I'd like my cells to dequeue as I've read on SO that if you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, it reuses the cells so it's more efficient.

Comment: Why don't you use the same code as before ? dequeue a cell, if it is `nil` initialise a new cell using swift [constructor](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:).

Comment: Since the cell is no longer `nil`, answers here are all outdated **except** for [Meilbn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43131560/5175709)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Keep in mind that `UITableView` is defined as an optional in the function, which means your initial cell declaration needs to check for the optional in the property. Also, the returned queued cell is also optional, so ensure you make an optional cast to `UITableViewCell`. Afterwards, we can force unwrap because we know we have a cell.

```
var cell:UITableViewCell? = 
tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell
if (cell == nil)
{
   cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, 
                reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
// At this point, we definitely have a cell -- either dequeued or newly created,
// so let's force unwrap the optional into a UITableViewCell
cell!.detailTextLabel.text = "some text"

return cell
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's that if statement which I was getting stuck on, and then the unwrapping!  Funnily enough, I watched the intermediate Swift talk from WWDC just now and they talk about this unwrapping!  Thanks again :)

Comment: NP. The syntax is still a little tricky for all of us, but it gets more natural the more you use it.

Comment: I'm getting fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None when I run this.

Comment: @RafaelBarros You set something up wrong and must not be getting a cell back.

Comment: I fixed it with the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056183/custom-uitableview-cell-iphone-using-swift-language?rq=1

Comment: @RafaelBarros I don't see how that relates to this question since that one is asking about custom cells.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons if I register the class as UITableViewCell.classForCoder() and try this, it just doesn't work. All I want is a subtitle and a thumbnail on the left. This just didn't work for me, with the exact same code.

Comment: @RafaelBarros The OP asked _specifically_ about dequeuing a standard `UITableViewCell` with subtitle style, _not_ a custom cell that needs to be registered to be dequeued. So I still fail to understand what your comment has to do with _this question_.

Comment: I'm not going to get into a flamewar with you defending your answer that is not working for me while trying to replicate exactly what this question is about, with only the subtitle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55213/discussion-between-michael-g-emmons-and-rafael-barros).

Comment: dequeueReusableCell always returns a cell since iOS 4.

Comment: For Swift 2 you have force it to:  cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "some text"
        return cell

Comment: shouldn't the check be `if cell == nil { // instantiate a new one }` ?

Comment: As @Andy said above `dequeueReusableCell()` no longer returns an optional in Swift 4. @Meilbn 's answer below is updated & correct.

Comment: @LShi Not quite. `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:forIndexPath:)` does indeed return a non-optional cell, but `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` still returns an optional.

Comment: This is answer is no longer valid. Because the cell is never `nil`. Can you udpate to match: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43131560/5175709 ?

Answer (score 68):

If you'd rather avoid optionality, you can make a subclass of UITableViewCell that looks something like this:

```
class SubtitleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Then register it using:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(SubtitleTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
```

This allows your cell customization code to be really nice:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = "foo"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "bar"

    return cell
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was breaking my head trying to figure out where .subtitle style gets set in the process of creating a custom cell tableView.

Comment: Do we have to subclassing UITableViewCell in this case? There is no other way we can register a cell with subtitle?

Comment: For the generic `UITableView` implementations this is the best way to go as far as I can understand.

Answer (score 20):

Basically the same as other answers, but I get around dealing with nasty optionals (you can't return `nil` from `-tableView:cellForRow:atIndexPath:` in Swift) by using a computed variable:

*Swift 3*

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UITableViewCell") else {
            // Never fails:
            return UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
        }
        return cell
    }()

    // (cell is non-optional; no need to use ?. or !)

    // Configure your cell:
    cell.textLabel?.text       = "Key"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Value"

    return cell
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Actually, it would be better to dequeue the cell using: `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` instead.

This later variant of the function automatically instantiates a new cell if no one is available for reusing (exactly what my code does explicitly above), and therefore *never* returns `nil`.

Comment: Rather than doing that interesting thing with the immediately invoked closure, you could just use the nil coalescing operator and say `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(...) ?? UITableViewCell(...)`.

Answer (score 14):

Just building upon memmons' answer by cleaning it up Swift 2 style...

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) ?? UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "some text"

return cell
```

Swift 3:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""

return cell
```

Answer (score 8):

Since `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:, for:)` return a non-nil cell, the `if cell == nil` check is always be false.
But I found a solution, to makes default style cell become what style(value1, value2 or subtitle) you want, because default style cell's `detailTextLabel` is nil, so check the `detailTextLabel` if it's nil, then create new style cell, and give it to dequeue cell, like:

Swift 3:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: yourCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

if cell.detailTextLabel == nil {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: repeatCellReuseIdentifier)
}

cell.textLabel?.text = "Title"
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Detail"

return cell
```

That's works for me.

Hope it's help.

Comment: Awesome! Also, to work with above guard statements use: 
`guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell"), cell.detailTextLabel != nil else { `

Comment: @HelloimDarius Thank you for your complement.

Comment: That code is inefficient because line 4 creates an extra cell, and if `repeatCellReuseIdentifier != yourCellReuseIdentifier`, that extra cell will never get reused.

Comment: @ma11hew28 As I said: ``tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:, for:)`` return a non-nil cell, if you want to avoid create extra cells, you can make your own subtitle style cell, my way just a lazy way. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let reuseIdentifier = "cell"
    var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell?
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    cell!.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Although the code might answer the question just fine, consider explaining it for a more comprehensive answer

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you should replace the "!=" on the if conditional for "=="

Answer (score 2):

You can use a slightly different syntax than the one from memmons to prevent the forced unwrapping:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell ?? UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, 
            reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "some text"

return cell
```

This is using XCode <s>6.1</s> 7, Swift <s>1.2</s> 2.0 syntax where `UITableView` is no longer an optional.

Comment: Swift 2 :  cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "some text"
        return cell

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using your own Custom Cell. Simply register UITableViewCell through code. Then you can prefer code.

Else select storyboard, select your TableViewCell -> Goto Attribute Inspector and choose the desired style as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are not registering any cell to the tableview.

If you did so, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will always give a non optional cell so UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle will never initiate.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect as suggested by Michael G. Emmons, but in Xcode 6.1 using

```
if !cell { .....
```

I get this error:

> Optional type '@|value UITableViewCell?' cannot be used as boolean ;
>   test for '!= nil' instead

The accepted syntax is:

```
if cell == nil { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:
 NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  
     var CellIdentifier:String = "Cell"  
     var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell  
     if cell == nil {  
        cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle(rawValue:3)!,reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier)   
      }
    return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    var cell:UITableViewCell? =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    if (cell != nil)
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle,
                               reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    cell!.textLabel?.text = "ABC"
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = "XYZ"

    return cell!

  }
```

Answer (score -2):

I engage you to look at this little UITableView-Example on Github: https://github.com/YANGReal/UITableView-Swift

They do like follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
   let cell = tableView .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
   cell.textLabel.text = String(format: "%i", indexPath.row+1)
   // set any other property of your cell here
   return cell
}
```

Comment: This is what the person in the video tutorial (link in original question) did but I'd like to use the cell style subtitle.  To do this, he created a separate subclass of UITableViewCell which I thought was unnecessary.  I hope it is, at least!