# How to use UITableViewCell with UITableViewCellStyle with cell reuse correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I want to use `UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle` style for the default table cells. I found an answer in [an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062285/how-to-set-uitableviewcellstylesubtitle-and-dequeuereusablecell-in-swift) like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell?
    if (cell != nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
}
```

With the code above, I can successfully use the Subtitle cell style. However, I start to think something might be wrong? Why create a new cell when `cell != nil`? In this way, you never reuse cells, isn't it? Besides, I can just call

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

I am having the same result. Why dequeue reusable cell & then create a new one? What is the right way to achieve cell reuse & at the time, to use `UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle` style for the cells?

**UPDATE**

Please note the first block of code is `cell != nil`, not `cell == nil`. If I change `cell == nil`, the code will not use the `Subtitle` style. I think the first works because it always create new cells with `Subtitle` style.

Comment: I think you're correct that it wouldn't reuse cells. What happens if you change it to `cell == nil`.

Comment: If I change `cell == nil`, the cells are not using `UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle` style

Comment: Are you registering a nib/class with your tableview? Do you have a prototype cell in a storyboard?

Comment: I don't have a nib/class for the cells. I register like this `tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")`, maybe it's somewhere to set the style?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're using `tableView.registerClass`, there is no way to override the style that it will pass to the class when each cell is created. A workaround I've used is to create a `UITableViewCell` subclass called `SubtitleCell` that always uses the `.subtitle` style.

```
import UIKit

class SubtitleCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
         super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
}
```

Then I register that class with the `tableView`

```
tableView.register(SubtitleCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Comment: hm... it's interesting... I think the answer about setting the style & cell resue at the same time is actually wrong then. It simply creates new cells.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically right; you dont need the second part of the code.

this:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

will give you a "new" cell if there is none to reuse or an existing one otherwise.

Comment: Are you sure? I think this will always create a new cell. The reuse identifier here is only used later by UITableView.dequeueReusableCell. If you think about it, it can't be right, there is no reference here to the table view object