# How to set tableview style to have subtitle programmatically while having dequeueReusableCell?

Tags: ios, swift

I want my tableView to have subtitle as well as being able to dequeue properly. I have referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062285/how-to-set-uitableviewcellstylesubtitle-and-dequeuereusablecell-in-swift) but it does not work for my code. What should I do?

My code is currently like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        //Calling tableview for a reusable cell here will always return a cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = developerArray[indexPath.row].developerName
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = developerArray[indexPath.row].developerHP

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: you might need to cast your cell as an optional UITableViewCell

Comment: double check you register your cell for tableView : tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

Comment: I think you're using UITableViewCell embeded in UITableView in Storyboard. Can you change this UITableViewCell type to subtitle and confirm result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swift 5**

//Declare the variable cell Identifier

```
let reuseCellIdentifier = “cellIdentifier”;
```

//Implementation of cellForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseCellIdentifier)
    if (!(cell != nil)) {

        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseCellIdentifier)
    }

    cell?.textLabel?.text = //Title text
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = //Subtitle text

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: The code is built successfully but the subtitle is not showing. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What about textLabel. It's displayed in your Screen.

Comment: Do one thing replace .subtitle with .value2 in line of code UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseCellIdentifier).

Comment: Do you have set any other properties in UITableview due to these this thing isn't working please check?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202542/discussion-between-rohit-parihar-and-anonymous).

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom cell using nib by adding labels

For creating custom cell refer this link:
[Custom UITableViewCell from nib in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541786/custom-uitableviewcell-from-nib-in-swift)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell

    cell.title.text = yourTitleArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailLbl.text = yourDetailArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, did you create your table using storyboard or code?

Either way you need to make sure you set the datasource and delegate to self, provided the class they are in conforms to :
UITableViewDataSource
and
UITableViewDelegate

```
myTable?.delegate = self
myTable?.dataSource = self
```

Also make sure you register your cell

```
myTable?.register(myCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
```

And when declaring your cell, you need to force it as the type

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
```

Below is a working sample of tableview with a created cell. I hope this helps.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    // Create the tableview object
    var myTable:UITableView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Set the size and location of the tableview
        myTable = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 600))
        // register your cell
        myTable?.register(myCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
        // set the background color of the table, note this wont make a difference unless the cell background is changed.
        myTable?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        // set the datasource and delegate to self
        myTable?.delegate = self
        myTable?.dataSource = self
        // This is jsut for style, wether there should be seperators or not, and if the user can select multiple lines
        myTable?.separatorStyle = .none
        myTable?.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        // Add the table to your view
        self.view.addSubview(myTable!)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // This is declaring how many rows you want in your table. I have 1 but you can do it according to the size of your array.
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // create the cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! myCell

        // set the title text for this cell
        cell.title.text = "HelloWorld"

        // return the cell
        return cell
    }
}
```

and this is the class for the cell we referenced above.

```
class myCell: UITableViewCell {


    var title = UILabel()
    var detail = UILabel()


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }



    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        title.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        title.textAlignment = .center
        self.contentView.addSubview(title)
        self.contentView.addSubview(detail)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        title.frame = CGRect(x: self.contentView.frame.width / 2 - 200, y: 6, width: 400, height: 20)
        detail.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 10, width: 280, height: 20)
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps. if you are doing it from story board let me know and I'll adjust.