# Custom cell in Xcode 6 + Swift not displaying

Tags: tableview, cell, swift, xcode6

I've searched a lot on the internet for a solution to this problem but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to create a custom cell in a table view.

I made a CustomCell.swift class to configure the labels I want in my custom cell, created it via storyboard (the first prototype cell in the tableview) and linked it with a identifier to the cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    let cellIdentifier = "huisCell"

    var cell: CustomCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? CustomCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }

    cell!.huisAdresLabel.text = "123"
    cell!.huisDetailLabel.text = "456"

    return cell
}
```

My CustomCell.swift code is like this:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var huisAdresLabel: UILabel
    @IBOutlet var huisDetailLabel: UILabel

}
```

It's very basic now, but I just want it to work because than I can expand the cell with more attributes and style it better.

Pictures via DropBox because I need 10 reputation to properly document my problem :)

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5v9jb6cqp80knze/AAD5-yPR8-KoStQddkqKIbcUa

I hope someone can explain what I'm doing wrong.

Edit:

To clear up some things, before my try to make a custom cell, I got it working with the basic cells, with the one label on the left hand side. But when I tried to style the tableview and created a custom cell it won't work.

Also, when testing different solutions I came across the problem that de two labels in CustomCell.swift are nil. Even when I made a custom init and did like a

```
self.huisAdresLabel = UILabel()
```

it was still nil. in the code that I showed you it prints the following:

```
<UILabel: 0xb2aadc0; frame = (0 -21; 42 21); text = '123'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0xb2aa3a0>>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that this method is even actually being called?  Most likely you haven't set the tableview's `datasource` properly.

Comment: Yes, I just did a println(cell) and it prints the following : "<_TtC14SchoonzichtApp10CustomCell: 0xd106c40; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0xd105fa0>>" edit: the println is just before the return statement.

Comment: I have exactly the same bug. It's definitely the bug from Xcode 6 beta versions!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093904/custom-uitableviewcell-shows-fatal-error-cant-unwrap-optional-none-issue-in/24113844#24113844

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I resolved this issue by overriding the following function, setting the height of the cells manually:

```
override func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->CGFloat
{
    return 44
}
```

Comment: you sir are a lifesaver. been stuck on this for over a week literally! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a xib file and adding your custom cell class to the 
"Table View Cell" that you create in your xib file.

(Make sure you reconnect it to the outlets in your custom cell class ;)

This link may help.
http://www.weheartswift.com/swifting-around/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem, but after disabling the "Use Auto Layout" under the "File Inspector", it did work!! and the Custom Cells are displayed

Note: I made the Custom Cells in the Builder, not in Code. Using Xcode beta 3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Working w/ Custom table cells in Xcode 6 Beta-4's IB, I found they all rendered on top of each other and my non-Custom cell.

I fixed my problem by...

1. selecting the Custom cell in IB
2. selecting the Size inspector (Option-Command-5)
3. in the Table View Cell section

   1. checking the Custom box
   2. keeping the default-provided 44 Row Height

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround: disable Use Size Classes, but still don't know is it bug or feature :-) needs more investigation or man reading.