# Custom Cell in UITableView giving error Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, xcode6

I am now totally stuck. Iv searched all over the place and cant seem to figure out why I keep getting this error - and to make it worse, the error log only shows `(lldb)`

I'm trying to show custom cells in my table. Each cell has a main label called `lblRouteNumber`, and then there are 2 labels on either side, `lblLeftStation` and `lblRightStation`.

Where I register my custom cell class with the table view:

> self.tblMain.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellTemplate")

My cell creator method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    var cell = tblMain.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellTemplate", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell
    cell.lblRouteNumber.text = "Routing"
    cell.lblLeftStation.text = "LEFT"
    cell.lblRightStation.text = "RIGHT"
    return cell
}
```

and my custom cell class:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var lblRouteNumber : UILabel
@IBOutlet var lblLeftStation : UILabel
@IBOutlet var lblRightStation : UILabel

init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

The app crashes on the line

> var cell = tblMain.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellTemplate", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell

and if I try assign anything to the label within, i get the `Cannot unwrap Optional.none` error.

[image: View Controller including UITableViewController]

Answer (score 0):

delete the following code from your  CustomTableViewCell

```
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
```

then i already answered here for this question

[Custom UITableviewcell shows "fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None" issue in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093904/custom-uitableviewcell-shows-fatal-error-cant-unwrap-optional-none-issue-in)

Comment: Tried that too... No luck. Iv practically copied what you had, but with my labels and things

Comment: did you connect IBOutlet properly ?

Comment: Yes sir. I just double checked

Comment: can you add screenshot of the error with your question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56334/discussion-between-mani-murugan-and-byron-coetsee).