# fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None custom table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, custom-cell

I am trying to assign text to UILabel in Custom Tableview Cell in Swift language. But It gives error stating **`"fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None"`**

My Custom Cell's code is as below

```
import UIKit

class NameTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var lblName: UILabel?

    init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        // Initialization code
    }


    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

and the way I use it in my VIewController's is as below

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
    {
        var cell:NameTableCell   = self.tblNames.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("nameCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as NameTableCell
        cell.lblName!.text="test"
        return cell
    }
```

I also tried the above function as suggested in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24113844/1030951

but couldn't succeed and getting the same error. Kindly Help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a checklist to make sure you are using custom cells correctly.

1. Make a prototype cell in InterfaceBuilder in your `TableView`.
2. With a `CustomCell` class written, use the inspector to change your
   prototype cell's class to `CustomCell`.
3. Add all `@IBOutlet` decorations to that prototype cell and connect them.
4. If you are changing your reuse identifier, make sure the identifier of the 
   prototype cell matches the one used in your code.
5. Your `tableView` function code should be as follows:

   `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {`

   `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIndentifier("ReuseID", for IndexPath:indexPAth) as CustomCell`

   `cell.customLabel.text = "some text"`

   `return cell`

I apologize for the code formatting, there seemed to be an issue with editing.

Comment: I have already changed it to my class as you suggested. yet it crashes.

Comment: Then the issue is with the label on the custom cell. The code `cell.lblName!.text` is causing the problem.

Comment: I see you have `@IBOutlet` for `lblName` in your custom cell class. Are you designing this cell in interface builder?

Comment: yes i am using story board and designing the cell in Interface builder.

Comment: So the same prototype cell has a label that is connected to that outlet?

Comment: yes its the same as is connected in the outlet. you may also face the same problem if you try the same code.

Comment: I've edited my answer. In code where I've used custom cells, I don't make any "decorations" like buttons or labels optionals.

Comment: I also tried in that way and it also crashes with emitting the same error.

Comment: Make sure the cell's identifier in IB is `nameCell` and remove the exclamation point from the return of that function. It should return `UITableViewCell`

Comment: I also tested by doing the same yet it gives the same error. I think it's having problem with initialising the label.

Comment: I'm running the same code without issue, which leads me to believe that something is awry with what you're doing in IB.

Answer (score 0):

What about.....

```
 cell.textLabel.text = "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to register nib (if there is any nib) in your viewDidLoad Method,

```
var nipName=UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle:nil)
tableView.registerNib(nipName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
```

If you are using storyboard then I think you need to register class for the same

```
tableView.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
```

and cellforRowAtIndexPath like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!{
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell
        cell.lblText.text = allList[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally my problem is solved but with a very strange solution.

My Cell's identifier was "nameCell" , when I change it to "NameCell" , it works fine.

I think "nameCell" identifier may be causing conflict with any system keyword.

I tried by debugging twice , app crashes when identifier is "nameCell" and works fine when identifier is "NameCell"

Comment: You mean that it crashes when it's `nameCell` in *both* the cell's reuse ID in Interface Builder and in your code? It makes sense that it would crash when the cell's reuse ID is `NameCell` in IB but `nameCell` when you try to retrieve it.

Comment: Its strange to say but I meant, same reuse ID in code and IB in both the cases but the problem was with "nameCell" , if I change that word or even its case as I did "NameCell" it works fine.

Comment: Time to file a bug report.