# Swift custom UITableviewCell width issue

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift

I have created a custom UITableviewCell in xcode 6 beta(5), but while testing on the simulator it looks too small, I tried to set the width using attribute inspector, and it didn't worked. I created it using a .xib file and I registered it in my mainViewController to use it with connected tableView

This is how it looks like in simulator

[image: The top left tiny gray part is my cell and the green is the background]

**The cell part of the code, where my custom class name is CustomCell**

```
 var cell:CustomCell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as CustomCell
 cell.txt.text="\(ListArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))"   
 return cell
```

**This is how I register in viewDidLoad**

```
 var nipName=UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle:nil)
 self.tableview.registerClass(CustomCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
 self.tableview.registerNib(nipName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Comment: Any help? will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my response to [UILabels in custom UITableViewCell never gets initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201381/uilabels-in-custom-uitableviewcell-never-gets-initialized) . First of all, code in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function. Second, depending on how you set up the nib/storyboard, if it already connected the tableview to the custom view, get rid of `registerClass`. Otherwise it'll disconnect your nib connection and recreate a new one, wiping out all the customization you did in the nib.

Comment: Thank's it works! Can you suggest a best way to put space between my cells? I mean space on left, right and bottom?

Comment: Please ask a new question for that (after uou check for existing answers).  Thanks. Also I'd appreciate your tagging this answer as accepted.