# Error when trying to set label's text

Tags: swift, uilabel

I'm trying to set the text of a label in a Prototype Cell. I've linked all of my `@IBOutlet`s properly. [Here are my files](https://github.com/ghostpotato/SE-UILabel-Nil). Example: `title.text = "Hi"` (assuming `title` is a label in my Proto Cell) gives this: `Value of type 'String?' has no member 'text'.`

How can I fix this?

I'm happy to provide additional information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to reopen the project then clean and build and run the project.

Comment: @ChathurangaSilva The problem still persists.

Comment: I've downloaded our project and run, It didn't show any errors , so where do you get this error ?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25217821/3066450

Comment: @ChathurangaSilva My bad, I didn't re-open my project. :P Post as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `X-code` has this error. And also there's no issues in your project, so I think you should:

1. Close the project
2. Reopen the project
3. then <kbd>Clean</kbd> => <kbd>Built</kbd> => <kbd>Run</kbd> the project.

This should solve your problem.