# How can I write [UITableViewCell class] in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

In Objective-c we can register class for `UITableView` by writing like this:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
```

But I cannot write `UITableViewCell` class in Swift. So how can I write `[UITableViewCell class]` in swift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView Using Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056183/uitableview-using-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to register your class:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```